# XAML GUI to Powershell with variables

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, powershell

A fellow member on Superuser got me onto [this guide](https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/10/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope/) on creating a GUI to a powershell script however I am new to this area so I need a little guidance on the coding.

This is the XAML code generated by Visual Studio 2015;

```
<Window x:Name="Title" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="New Mailbox" Height="400" Width="420">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="14,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="386" Source="C:\Users\Daniel Neocleous\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Images\SibelcoLogo.png"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton" Content="Step 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioButton_Copy" Content="Step 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Create Mailbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" Height="35"/>
    <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="169" Margin="10,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="394">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="147" Margin="0,0,-1.143,-0.714" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384"/>
    </GroupBox>

</Grid>
```

Now from what I have understood I have to modify this code by removing the x's and the `x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"` string and add the following to the end;

```
#Read XAML
    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
    try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
    catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."; exit}
    #===========================================================================
    # Store Form Objects In PowerShell
    #===========================================================================
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}
    #===========================================================================
    # Shows the form
    #===========================================================================
    $Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

I am a little stuck from here though assuming what I have out above is correct. How do I tie all this to the Gui?

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISMrd.png)

There are two Radio buttons and depending which one is selected I want a different script to run and the Powershell output to be displayed in the text box at the bottom but how can I accomplish this?

The Powershell I want to run on Step 1

```
$credentials = get-credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri URL -Credential $credentials –AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true
Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity test@test.com -RemoteRoutingAddress test@test.com.onmicrosoft.com
Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity test@test.com -Archive
```

Step 2

```
$msolcred = get-credential
connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName test@test.com -UsageLocation GB
$LicOpt = New-MsolLicenseOptions -AccountSkuId company:STANDARDPACK -DisabledPlans MCOSTANDARD
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName test@test.com -AddLicenses company:STANDARDPACK -LicenseOptions $LicOpt
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Thanks for the advice guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$Form` should be a `Window` object and thus support all its methods, so to react to certain events you have to read the state of the controls.

As this is script based, i would just name all the relevant parts and search for them using [`FindName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) (your script apparently already creates powershell variables for all named controls). You then can access the properties like `IsChecked` to differentiate which `RadioButton` is selected. To listen to a button click you probably need [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx). As you use `ShowDialog` you have a blocking call that returns when the [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) is set, so you should set that in your event listener.

**Edit:** I just played around with this and here's a small sample that shows the basic process.

ScriptWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Name="Title"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="selection" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                                 Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <sys:String>Step 1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Step 2</sys:String>
        </ListBox>
        <Button x:Name="run">Run</Button>
        <GroupBox Header="Output">
            <TextBox x:Name="output" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ScriptWindow.ps1

```
Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type –assemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type –assemblyName WindowsBase

$xaml="ScriptWindow.xaml"
$xmlReader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader $xaml)
$app=(New-Object System.Windows.Application)
$form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $xmlReader )
$doc=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument)
$doc.Load($xaml)
$run = $form.FindName("run")
$selection = $form.FindName("selection")
$output = $form.FindName("output")
$run.Add_Click({ $output.Text = $selection.SelectedItem })
$app.Run($form)
```

Apparently you can also add event listeners via `Add_*`, `Register-ObjectEvent` did not work for me. In the callback i just assign the selected option to the `TextBox`, you will want to do a case distinction on the selected value and execute your respective actions.

Comment: Is the overall code correct? I'm new to scripting and coding so I am a little unfamiliar with some of the terms. Do I alter the PS script with things like FindName or the GUI part?

Comment: It's worth noting that if the original guide is followed they generate variables for each object with the variable names starting with `$WPF`, and it will list all of the variables for you. Then you just find your button, and execute the `.Add_Click({<action goes here>})` method on it.

Comment: @H.B. Thank you very much for that. I'm a little confused with the Powershell script you've written from what I've understood it links to the buttons and various controls on the GUI but how does the GUI and the ScriptWindow.ps1 file call the the Step 1 and Step 2 powershell scripts?

Comment: @DanielNeocleous: They don't, as i said, you'll need to make that case distinction in that code block of `Add_Click`, should be trivial.